# Find the sum of this given expression.....

Tags: arithmetic

$$1+(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)$$

Comment: If one-line answers are rarely good, so too with one-line questions.  It would greatly improve your post to indicate what you've tried, or even what makes such an exercise interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

We have
\begin{align}
&1+(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)\\
&\quad=1+\frac{(3-1)(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)}{2}\\
&\quad=1+\frac{3^{64}-1}{2}\\
&\quad=\frac{3^{64}+1}{2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S=1+(3+1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)$$
Then,
\begin{align*}
(3-1)S&=(3-1)+(3^2-1)(3^2+1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)\\[3pt]
2S&=2+(3^4-1)(3^4+1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)\\[3pt]
&=2+(3^8-1)(3^8+1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)\\[3pt]
&=2+(3^{16}-1)(3^{16}+1)(3^{32}+1)\\[3pt]
\vdots&=\vdots\\
&=2+3^{64}-1\\
&=3^{64}+1
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\boxed{\color{blue}{S=\frac{3^{64}+1}{2}}}$$